# Quit downvoting me for no reason

Tags: discussion

You guys argue and downvote me for no reason and it should stop please.

This answer was accepted as correct and still got downvotes:
[Can I make an App that looks like snapchat?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/41037/can-i-make-an-app-that-looks-like-snapchat/41038?noredirect=1#comment75449_41038)

This answer was 100% correct and got multiple downvotes:
[after indictment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/41029/after-indictment/41030?noredirect=1#comment75490_41030)

Answer (score 8):

You get downvoted, because your answers are just not good.

I just looked at some of your other answers; https://law.stackexchange.com/a/41040/65, for example.  You answer the question without actually answering it; the asker is clearly unfamiliar with the term "independent contractor", and you never bother to define it, neither in the answer, nor in the comments to it.  (Is the answer actually on the external page you link?  That's against the rules as well.)  Someone else answers it fully correctly; instead of admitting your answer is no good, you go around complaining that their answer is wrong, when it's clearly not.

And just because your answer got accepted by the asker doesn't mean that it is, or that it should be, immune to downvoting, either.  Some folks just accept the answers by mistake, because they don't know any better, or to get rid of SE nagging them to accept an answer, so, that's not much of a proof either way that the answer is or is not correct.

I presume that some of these answers are downvoted because they feel more like "comments" to other people.  On StackOverflow, the main QA site, for example, it is customary to answer questions with comments if you don't want to write a fully-detailed and explanatory answer; I suggest that you might follow this approach if you want to provide one-line comments without writing a full answer, especially if you're concerned about the downvotes.

Comment: I'll admit I misread his answer in the one you linked to and I told him that. That doesn't change all the senseless down votes though.

Comment: Maybe they would get more than one sentence, if people didn't down vote everything. @ohwilleke was clearly wrong here and chewed me out look at this https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/30349/payable-in-like-kind-non-electing-shares/39197#39197 You guys have done this when proven wrong and then get mad when I don't want to put in the effort and get downvoted bc you are mad you were proven wrong in the past.

Comment: @putvi regardless of the reason, complaining about downvotes on meta is inappropriate and pointless. We cannot do anything about it and you are destroying whatever goodwill people have towards you, if they read this at all; I can't think that anyone would be inclined to downvote you *less* after reading a post like this. I would suggest not complaining about downvotes in this way, and if you feel that you cannot cope with them, then perhaps this is the not the right site for you.